# Complete http.Request asynchronously in Golang

Tags: go

I want to put all arriving `http.Request`s into a queue and have a separate thread (`goroutine`?) process these requests and return the appropriate status.

However, the main `http request` handler directly completes the request even when the `http.Request` object is sent asynchronously to a `goroutine`.

Is there a way to control when the `http.Request` is completed and thereby asynchronously process it?

[Update]

I want to implement a producer-consumer model. The main request handler produces the requests and put them into a queue. A consumer thread (or threads) will read these requests, consume the body of the requests and return them.

Comment: I have to admit I do not understand what's your question here? Package net/http _does_ process request asynchronously already. And of course: If a handler completes the request is done. If you don't want this your handler should not terminate but do your other work you intend to do asynchronously.

Comment: Good to know that the net/http package handles http requests asynchronously. But I want to push all http requests into a queue from the handler (producer) and have another thread (consumer) read these requests and its data and return them (I'll update the main question with some of this for better visibility).

Comment: Okay, I think this is nonsensical as this make request processing a **synchronous** process, but it can be done: The request handler pushes the request into channel 1 and _waits_ (!!) until the consumer has processed the request by waiting on the result on channel 2. The consumer listens on channel 1, grabs request, processes them and returns to producer via channel 2. Complete serial processing. Don't do that, it is nonsense. The Go http server _is_ already a producer and your handlers _are_ consumers, there is no need to redo this work.

Comment: The data sent via the http requests needs to be written to disk. I'll obviously benchmark this, but generally having multiple threads writing to a single rotational disks isn't a good idea as it can increase the # of seeks.

Comment: It sounds there's some confusion here: do you mean `http.Request` (as in a server) or `http.Response` (i.e. your application is a HTTP **client**). If you want to write a client that can issue (e.g.) 50+ requests concurrently and then push the `http.Response` into a channel so you can digest the `http.Response.Body`s one-by-one (i.e. write to disk) then that's a different thing.

Comment: I want to write a server. This server receives multiple `http.Request`'s (PUT requests) and writes the body of each of those requests into file/s.

Answer (score 1):

http handlers are executed in a different goroutine per request, so if you are simply trying to free up the main serve loop, it's not neccesary.

If you are looking to serialize processing of requests, you could use a `sync.Mutex` and have your handler's lock on that. This would have a similar effect in that the requests would be handled one at a time.

I don't think `sync.Mutex` is fair, so it may not meet your needs.

also, if you wanted to be stateful between requests, then this is probably not the right solution.

As Jorge Marey mentioned, channels would work as well.

Though, i'd suggest you look at [golang.org/x/net/context](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context) as it is a package specifically designed for multi-stage processing with timeouts and whatnot.

my guess is you will end up with a channel that passes structs that look like:

```
type Req struct{
   ctx context.Context
   w http.ResponseWriter
   r *http.Request
}
```